# Canvas touch-pan-scroll enabled

Tags: canvas, scroll

Here is the canvas example on this page: http://brekalo.info/en/references.
Domain names are loaded in the canvas and by clicking on the domain name we can open it in the new window.

On mobile devices users need to touch-pan-scroll page, but the canvas doesn't allow that unless css **pointer-events: none** is applied.

If I set **pointer-events: none** then my clicking event is disabled.

**HTML**

```
<section id="pixi-frame" class="pixi-frame">
    <canvas></canvas>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#pixi-frame {
    pointer-events: none;
}

canvas { 
    pointer-events: all; 
}
```

The above css code not working.

This one works, allowing touch-drag on canvas:

```
canvas { 
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

.. but it disables canvas click event!